# JavaScript - Loop over all a tags, add an onclick to each one

Tags: javascript

I've got a list of links that point to images, and a js function that takes a URL (of an image) and puts that image on the page when the function is called.

I was originally adding an inline onlick="showPic(this.getAttribute('href'))" to each a, but I want to separate out the inline js. Here's my func for adding an onclick to each a tag when the page loads:

```
function prepareLinks(){
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
    var thisLink = links[i];
    var source = thisLink.getAttribute('href'); 
    if(thisLink.getAttribute('class') == 'imgLink'){
        thisLink.onclick = function(){
            showPic(source);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}

function showPic(source){
var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
placeholder.setAttribute('src',source);
}

window.onload = prepareLinks();
```

...but every time showPic is called, the source var is the href of the last image. How can I make each link have the correct onclick?

Comment: Don't want to use jQuery and make this a veritable one-liner?

Comment: Your `window.onload` is wrong. That will assign the return of `prepareLinks()` to the `load` event of `window`.

Comment: @alex: good catch, didn't even see that

Comment: Kirk - thanks but this needs to be normal js-only.
@alex - Thanks, have addressed that in the solution I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies. Turns out I had diagnosed the problem incorrectly, sorry. Actually using a new var and annon. function to add an onclick on each loop iteration works (the passed href is correct). It was not working because I was getting at the a-tags by the "imgLink" class which I had removed from the HTML when I removed the inline onclick handlers (I get them with an ID on a parent now). Also I needed to use "return !showPic(this.href);" to stop the link being followed normally when clicked.

Working code:

```
function showPic(source){
var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
placeholder.setAttribute('src',source);
return true;
}

function prepareLinks() {
if(!document.getElementById('imgLinks')){ return false; };
var galLinks = document.getElementById('imgLinks');
var links = galLinks.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    var thisLink = links[i];
    thisLink.onclick = function() {
        return !showPic(this.href);
    };
}
}

window.onload = function(){
prepareLinks();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript doesn't have block scope, so the closed variable ends up being whatever was last assigned to it. You can fix this by wrapping it in another closure:

```
function prepareLinks() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var thisLink = links[i];
        var source = thisLink.getAttribute('href'); 
        if(thisLink.getAttribute('class') == 'imgLink') {
            thisLink.onclick = (function(source) {
                return function() {
                    showPic(source);
                    return false;
                };
            })(source);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can make this one simpler and use `this`:

```
function prepareLinks() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var thisLink = links[i];

        if(thisLink.getAttribute('class') == 'imgLink') {
            thisLink.onclick = function() {
                showPic(this.href);
                return false;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this either breaks compatibility with IE5 or IE6, but hopefully you don't care about either of those =)

Comment: Block scope wouldn't fix this problem. Also, if you just grab the source from the handler, you don't need to create all those extra scopes

Comment: @JuanMendes: Actually, block scope would really fix this problem. As for getting it from the handler - already added ;)

Comment: I still disagree, I don't think block scope would fix it, `source` in defined in the same block as all the handlers

Comment: @JuanMendes: That really doesn't matter. Take [this C#](http://ideone.com/kVbbn) for example, which does use block scope to solve the problem.

Comment: Wish I knew C# better, I don't fully understand the code. But you had to add a new variable `j` in that example, just printing `i` would output 5... To me block scope just means that a variable is not reachable outside of that block. A block scope variable could be brought into a closure... :p

Comment: @JuanMendes: Yeah, C#'s `foreach` loops are like that. Half-and-half in either scope. But it's not a closure :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10028/discussion-between-juan-mendes-and-minitech)

Answer (score 2):

Minitech's answer should fix your problem, which is that the `source` variable is shared by all your onclick handlers

The way you're doing it is very wasteful, there's no need to set a separate handler for each link. Also, it won't work if any links are added dynamically. Event delegation is the way to go.

```
function interceptLinks() {
   // Bad way to set onclick (use a library)
   document.onclick = function() {
     if (this.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'A' ) {
       return;
     }
     // Bad way to check if it contains a class (use a library)
     if (this.getAttribute('class') == 'imgLink') {
       showPic(this.getAttribute('href'));
       return false;
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the age-old problem of event handlers inside of a loop that access an outer variable.

Your `source` variable is pulled off the scope chain at the time of the `click` event, and by then, it's been set to the last `href` attribute due to the iteration being finished.

You need to break the closure by doing one of two things.

The easiest but not supported by many browsers is to use `let` which lets you use block scope.

```
let source = thisLink.getAttribute('href');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcvd2/). It worked in Firefox, but not Chrome.

In 2038, when we're dealing with the [year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) and all browsers have implemented ES6, this will be the standard way to *fix* this problem.

A more difficult to understand and implement method that is compatible with all browsers is to break the closure with a pattern such as...

```
thisLink.onclick = (function(src) {
  return function(){
            showPic(src);
            return false;
        }
})(source);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6LYj/).

Comment: `let` is not EcmaScript (yet), it's Mozilla's JavaScript, hopefully, it will make it into EcmaScript soon

Comment: @JuanMendes [It's on its way](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:let).